# PHP preg_match and regex: lowercaps only either with hyphens, numbers, or alphabets, and at least 6 characters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, lowercase

I want to accept an input with **lowercaps only either with hyphens, numbers, or alphabets, and at least 6 characters**. But the regex below accepts Upper case as long as the input is longer than 6 characters.

```
$user_name = 'BloggerCathrin';

if(!preg_match('/([a-z0-9]{6}|[a-z0-9\-]{6})/', $user_name))
{
    echo 'please use lowercaps only, either with hyphens, numbers, or alphabets, and at least 6 characters.';
}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: You are okay for partial match. If you need to match the whole string from beginning until end, use `/^...$/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pattern needs to match the whole string - from beginning to end - you need to wrap it inside `^` and `$`:

```
      /^([a-z0-9]{6}|[a-z0-9\-]{6})$/
start -´                           `- end
```

From [*PCRE regex syntax - Meta-characters*](http://php.net/regexp.reference.meta) :

> `^` - assert start of subject (or line, in multiline mode)
>   `$` - assert end of subject or before a terminating newline (or end of line, in multiline mode)

---

If you have a six character minimum (and you also can compact), your pattern might look like:

````
 /^[a-z0-9-]{6,}$/
             ```- minimum: 6, maximum: unspecified (empty)
````

Comment: You also need to change your pattern if I follow your question right.

Comment: `/^([a-z0-9]{6}|[a-z0-9\-]{6})$/` only takes 6 chars, I need to take more than 6...

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Refresh, you should see an edit, that's just what I meant.

Answer (score 5):

Anchor your string with `^` at the start and `$` at the end.

```
"/^[a-z0-9-]{6,}$/"
```